# External Libraries in Certain Components Angular 5

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) library into my project. I've been able to install the npm package. However, now I need to add a script to my index.html. This library will only be used by the page admin. Is there a way for me to add the script only to the `AdminComponent` where an admin could create new pages? Otherwise the library will be loaded but almost never used, and it's about 500kb, which is considerable when aiming for performance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an angular way but you can append a `<script>` tag in your HTML head tag
by adding the below code in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook of `AdminComponent`

```
const ckEditorScript = document.createElement('script');
ckEditorScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js');
document.head.appendChild(ckEditorScript);
```

This way the script will be downloaded only if user navigates to `AdminComponent`

Comment: The thing with doing that is that CKEditor needs to initialize itself, and without the library it can't. So when I add it "dynamically" it has already tried to initialize and didn't find the library so it prints "CKEditor 4.x is missing". I also tried adding it with document.write() and the page won't load. Can you think of a solution for that?

Comment: @TomasPiaggio I've managed to solve this issue, by adding a setTimeout() method for the property initialisation, that handles the Editor visibility: `setTimeout(() => { this.isScriptLoaded = true; }, 500)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue with a mixture of the previous answer, and some additional code. Instead of adding the whole script to the `index.html` I ended up adding just an if statement on load:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if(CKEDITOR) {
    const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea);
  }
})
```

If the CKEDITOR exists in window, then it will initialize it. After this code was added, I wrote the following in the component I intend to use the editor:

```
const ckEditorScript = document.createElement('script');
ckEditorScript.setAttribute('src','https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js');
document.head.appendChild(ckEditorScript);
```